# Why do I get garbage when I try to parse the binary file in C++?

Tags: c++, wav

I'm trying to parse .wav files in C++.
The 44 bytes in the header of the .wav file are some of the file's meta information, which I am trying to parse.
I parsed it in Python and got the following, which should be correct

```
Chunk_id  :  RIFF
Chunk_size  :  468556
Format  :  WAVE
fmt_id  :  fmt 
fmt_size  :  16
audio_format  :  1
channels_count  :  1
sample_rate  :  44100
byte_rate  :  88200
block_align  :  2
bits_per_sample  :  16
data_id  :  data
data_size  :  468520
```

But when I switch in to C++, I got this:

```
ChunkID: RIFFL&
ChunkSize: 468556
Format: WAVEfmt 
FmtID: fmt 
FmtChunkSize: 16
FmtAudioFormat: 1
FmtChannelNumber: 1
FmtSampleRate: 44100
FmtByteRate: 88200
FmtBlockAlign: 2
FmtBitPerSample: 16
DataChunkID: data(&
```

The problem is three fields consisting of a char array of four bytes.

`ChunkID: RIFFL&`, `Format: WAVEfmt`, `DataChunkID: data(&`
As parsed by Python, the contents of the three fields should be `RIFF`, `WAVE`, `data`.
And this is my C++ code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
struct WaveChunk
{
        char ChunkID[4];
        int ChunkSize;
        char Format[4];

        // fmt
        char FmtID[4];
        int FmtChunkSize;
        short FmtAudioFormat;
        short FmtChannelNumber;

        int FmtSampleRate;
        int FmtByteRate;
        short FmtBlockAlign;
        short FmtBitPerSample;
        // fmt

        // data
        char DataChunkID[4];
        int DataChunkSize;
        // data
};

string WaveChunkToString(WaveChunk* wavechunk){
    stringstream ss;
    ss << "ChunkID: " << wavechunk->ChunkID << "\n";
    ss << "ChunkSize: " << wavechunk->ChunkSize << "\n";
    ss << "Format: " << wavechunk->Format << "\n";

    ss << "FmtID: " << wavechunk->FmtID << "\n";
    ss << "FmtChunkSize: " << wavechunk->FmtChunkSize << "\n";
    ss << "FmtAudioFormat: " << wavechunk->FmtAudioFormat << "\n";
    ss << "FmtChannelNumber: " << wavechunk->FmtChannelNumber << "\n";
    ss << "FmtSampleRate: " << wavechunk->FmtSampleRate << "\n";
    ss << "FmtByteRate: " << wavechunk->FmtByteRate << "\n";
    ss << "FmtBlockAlign: " << wavechunk->FmtBlockAlign << "\n";
    ss << "FmtBitPerSample: " << wavechunk->FmtBitPerSample << "\n";
    ss << "DataChunkID: " << wavechunk->DataChunkID << "\n";
    ss << "DataChunkSize: " << wavechunk->DataChunkSize << endl;
    return ss.str();
}

using namespace std;
int main(){
    WaveChunk w;
    ifstream inf("target.wav", ios::binary|ios::in);
    inf.read((char* ) &w, sizeof(WaveChunk));
    cout << WaveChunkToString(&w);
    return 0;
}
```

That's it, why are these three fields parsed differently than expected, but the other fields made up of numbers are fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this line and the other lines to print `char something[4];`:

```
    ss << "ChunkID: " << wavechunk->ChunkID << "\n";
```

`std::stringstream` will read until null-character `'\0'` but the array doesn't contain that, so it will read beyond the allocated buffer.

You will have to specify the size to print for properly printing the array without adding extra byte.
It can be done like this:

```
    ss << "ChunkID: "; ss.write(wavechunk->ChunkID, 4); ss << "\n";
```